# HighChart : update group column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

For example i have a chart like below

```
$("#tester").highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        height:320
    },
    series: [{name: 'Postive',data: sPositiveTotal}, 
            {name: 'Neutral',data: sNeutralTotal}, 
            {name: 'Negative',data: sNegativeTotal}]
});
```

And i tried to update the data with a button, i do

```
var SentimentChart = $("#tester").highcharts();
SentimentChart.series[0].setData([{name: 'Postive',data: sPositiveTotal}, {name: 'Neutral',data: sNeutralTotal}, {name: 'Negative',data: sNegativeTotal}]);
```

But it doesn't as  i except, how may i update it correctly?

fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/cmeubLr2/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`setData` method](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) is called on a specific series, so you have to do the update for each individual series. It also expects just data, not series options.

So for example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmeubLr2/2/)):

```
changeData.series[0].setData([124, 5435, 16434, 129.2, 144.0, 176576.0, 176535.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]);
changeData.series[1].setData([8753.6, 66.8, 98.5, 93.4, 175606.0, 84.5, 107655.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]);
// ...
```

If you want to update the options as well you can use [`update`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) instead ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmeubLr2/3/)):

```
changeData.series[0].update({
    name: 'Beijing',
    data: [124, 200, 200, 129.2, 144.0, 200.0, 200.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
});
```

Comment: Awesome! I now see the usage of the series[i]